# Visual Studio, issue with running project

Tags: visual-studio

I'm just a day new at this, so sorry for asking stupid questions...

2 issues...

Can I save a whole project in one file in VS?

I'm trying to run a simple project, but get the error:

Warning 1 Could not copy "obj\Debug\WindowsApplication9.exe" to "bin\Debug\WindowsApplication9.exe". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\WindowsApplication9.exe' because it is being used by another process.   WindowsApplication9

What does "being used by another process" mean?

the project is not open anywhere else when I'm trying to run this, so I don't understand...

Pls help.

Comment: In my code I have a Me.Hide()... Is it hiding my form without closing it? And how do I close it properly?
I've tried with Me.Close() but that just closes all my forms, and I don't want that...

Comment: What programming language and what framework do you use? Post reasonable quantity of related code, so we can get idea on what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Check task manager for an already running `WindowsApplication9.exe`.  You can't build your project if it is still running.  Your `Me.Hide` call sounds like the culprit if your app is running in task manager and you can't see the window.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this when attempting to run unit tests. The culprit turned out to be multiple MSBuild processes locking the files. I nuked them via Task Manager, and was able to run my tests again.